# axios request error: "Could not connect to the server."

Tags: react-native, axios, fastapi

i am responsible for the fronted(written in the react native), i want to sent a simple request to the server with login params, but i am getting following error

```
 ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined]
 ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined]
 ERROR  Network Error
 ERROR  AxiosError
 ERROR  ERR_NETWORK
 ERROR  {"adapter": ["xhr", "http"], "data": "{\"username\":\"adrian\",\"password\":\"123\"}", "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json"}, "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "post", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "http://0.0.0.0:80/token", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}
 ERROR  {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": true, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "content-type": "application/json"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {}, "_method": "POST", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://0.0.0.0:80/token", "_performanceLogger": {"_closed": false, "_extras": {}, "_isLoggingForWebPerformance": false, "_pointExtras": {}, "_points": {"initializeCore_end": 687811160.947458, "initializeCore_start": 687811102.854}, "_timespans": {"network_XMLHttpRequest_http://0.0.0.0/token": [Object], "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://0.0.0.0:80/token": [Object], "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://localhost:8081/symbolicate": [Object], "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://0.0.0.0/token": [Object]}}, "_requestId": null, "_response": "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "http://0.0.0.0:80/token", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": undefined, "status": 0, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}
 ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'msg' of undefined]
```

The backend is implemented in FastAPI (Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80). Although I'm not responsible for the backend, I attempted to add CORS without success. The backend isn't receiving any requests (only requests from FastAPI docs), and I'm only seeing errors from the frontend.
Here is my login function:

```js
const login = async (username: string, password: string) =>{
        try{
            const result = await axios.post(`http://0.0.0.0:80/token`, {username, password});

            setAuthState({
                token: result.data.access_token,
                authenticated: true
            })

            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${result.data.access_token}`;

            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, result.data.access_token);

            return result;
        }catch(e){
            console.error(e.message);
            console.error(e.name);
            console.error(e.code);
            console.error(e.config);
            console.error(e.request);
        }
    }
```

In my opinin fronted want to sent request from https when backend is set to the http but i am not sure if it is problem and i dont know what cause real problem, do we need to change backed to use https? Is any other solution to this problem?

main.py:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from routes import router, init_db
from database import engine, test_connection

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

origins = [
    "http://localhost:8081",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"], 
    allow_headers=["*"],  
)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    await init_db(engine)
    await test_connection()
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "until nc -z db 5432; do sleep 1; done; uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:12345@db:5432/postgres

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

post method:

```js
@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()],
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)
):
    user = await authenticate_user(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)

    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = await create_access_token(
        data={"sub" : user.username, "scopes" : form_data.scopes},
        expires_delta=access_token_expires,
    )

    return {"access_token" : access_token, "token_type" : "bearer"}
```

Comment: Can you share  FastAPI  code too?

Comment: added, want you see docker-compose file or post method?

Comment: Can you make a post request to the server in another client such as Postman?

Comment: Yes, docker-compose file and post method too.

Comment: @PatrickGorman it works without any problems

Comment: Good, I think it is port 8081->80 issue.

Comment: @BenchVue  Metro waiting on http://localhost:8081

Answer (score 0):

i think the url should be like that
`http://ipaddress:80/token`

if using docker you can put the container name or it's host ip instead of ipaddress

also check for port if not match

0.0.0.0
is used in server to allow connection from any where outside the server
you may set it in origin to allow any connection or simple put origin like below

origin: '*'

also that will allow any origin if you want to allow any connection from outside the server

i hope that will help you